# vx.from_pandas(df).export_hdf5(path) giving KeyError while writing pandas df to HDF5 file

Tags: python, pandas, vaex, dramatiq

Software information

Vaex version : 4.1.0

Vaex was installed via: pip from source

OS: Windows Server 2016

Python Version : Python 3.9.7

Additional information

Backend application while trying save the pandas df to HDF5 file using code vx.from_pandas(df).export_hdf5(path) errors out. Exception Stack Trace attached as image.

Unfortunately, the stated exception is not reproducible. The next time when i try to save the same df, it successfully saves.

[image]